# Unicorn restart issue when deploying my rails app (capistrano)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn, capistrano3

I'm trying to get my rails app up and running on my VPS (`Ubuntu 14`, `Ruby 2.3`, `Rails 4`, `Capistrano 3`, `Nginx 1.4.6`, `Unicorn 5`). Unfortunately I'm running into some issue with starting / restarting `Unicorn`

`Capistrano` gives me the following error:

> DEBUG [e0b4d317] Command: /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp restart
>
> DEBUG [e0b4d317] Couldn't reload, starting 'cd /var/www/myapp/current; bundle exec unicorn -p 3000 -D -c
>   /var/www/myapp/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production' instead
>
> DEBUG [e0b4d317] master failed to start, check stderr log for details
>   (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
>
> cap aborted!

`/shared/log/unicorn_error.log` tells me:

> E, [2016-03-09T18:02:28.795300 #32208] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:3000 (in use)
>
> /var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:149:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

I'm quite new to this. What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: Could you share your unicorn configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar issue, what helped was to put

```
listen 3000, reuseport: true
```

`reuseport: true` to my unicorn.rb